# Mongodb aggregation pipeline issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, aggregation-framework

With mongodb, I want to get all account list, by removing the duplicate ones (those who have the same accountType value) so I can one document per accountType property and assign to it a new id:

This is the model code:

```
import { Schema, model } from "mongoose";
import {
  accountFeesEnum,
  accountTypesEnum,
} from "../utilities/constants/types";
import deletePlugin from "mongoose-delete";

interface AccountInterface {
  accountType: string;
  accountExpiration?: Date;
  feesPerPersonPerMonth: number;
}

const AccountSchema = new Schema<AccountInterface>(
  {
    accountType: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      enum: accountTypesEnum,
    },
    accountExpiration: {
      type: Date,
    },
    feesPerPersonPerMonth: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      enum: accountFeesEnum,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

AccountSchema.plugin(deletePlugin);

const Account = model("Account", AccountSchema);
export default Account;
```

And this is the code of getAccountList() controller (it is a part of a bigger class):

```
async getAccountList(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<any> {
    try {
       let currentUser = await User.findOne({ _id: (req as any).user.id });

       if (currentUser?.userType !== SuperAdmin) {
         return res.status(FORBIDDEN).json({
           errors: [{ msg: "Only Super Admin can remove accounts!" }],
         });
       }

      const pipeline = [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: { accountType: "$accountType", accountFees: "$accountFees" },
            count: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            accountType: "$_id.accountType",
            accountFees: "$_id.accountFees",
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: { $toString: { $add: ["$$REMOVE", ""] } },
            accountType: 1,
            accountFees: 1,
          },
        },
      ];
      let accountList = await Account.aggregate(pipeline);
      if (accountList?.length == 0) {
        return res.status(NOT_FOUND).json({
          errors: [{ msg: "Cannot find any accounts!" }],
        });
      }

      return res.status(OK).json({ accountList });
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error(error.message);
      res
        .status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        .send("Server Error! Something went wrong!");
    }
  }
```

The issue is that I got a list of all accounts but all their ids are null and I only get the accountTypes values where I want to get all data of account. How to fix the pipeline ?

The other question is how to solve the type problem with `req` ? I used to write `(req as any).body` as the body property is not defined in Request type (Typescript issue)